# uWSGI + builded Go .so not working

Tags: python, django, excel, go, uwsgi

**Problem**: .so(shared object) as library in python works well when `python` calls it and fails in uWSGI-running python(Django) application.

**More info**: I've build Go module with `go build -buildmode=c-shared -o output.so input.go` to call it in Python with

```
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('path_to_library/output.so')
```

When django project is served via uWSGI the request handler that calling *Go library* freezes, causing future 504 in Nginx. After getting in "so called freeze", uWSGI is locked there and only restarting helps to enliven app. No logs AT ALL! It just freezes.

**Everything works correctly when i run in python interpreter** on the same machine.

*My thoughts*: i've tried to debug this and put a lot of log messages in library, but it won't give much info because everything is fine with library(because it works in interpreter). Library loads correctly, because some log messages that i've putted in library. I think it some sort of uWSGI limitation. I don't think putting uwsgi.ini file is somehow helpful.

#### Additional info:

- *Go dependencies*:

  - `fmt`
  - [`github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize`](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize)
  - `log`
  - `encoding/json`
- OS: CentOS 6.9
- Python: Python 3.6.2
- uWSGI: 2.0.15

What limitations can be in uWSGI in that type of shared object work and if there a way to overcome them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Attempts and thoughts

I tried to avoid separation of shared library from my python code, since it requires support of at least one more process, and i would have to rewrite some of the library to create new api.

As [@Lu.nemec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48754446/3124746) kindly noted that:

> Go has its own runtime, thread management and may not work well with uWSGI which handles threads/processes in a different way

Since uWSGI is the problem i started seaching for a solution there. One of the hopes was installing [GCCGO uWSGI plugin](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GCCGO.html) somehow solve that problem. But even it's hard to install on old OSes, because it lacks of pre-builded plugins and manual build haven't gone very well, it haven't helped, nothing changes, it still freezes.

And then i thought that i wan't to disable coroutines and that type of stuff that differs from uWSGI and one of the changes that i am able to do is to set [`GOMAXPROCS`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS)

> `GOMAXPROCS` sets the maximum number of CPUs that can be executing simultaneously and returns the previous setting. If n < 1, it does not change the current setting. The number of logical CPUs on the local machine can be queried with NumCPU. This call will go away when the scheduler improves.

And it worked like a charm!!!

### The solution

```
import (
    ...
    "runtime"
)
...
//export yourFunc
func yourFunc(yourArgs argType) {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are you absolutely positive you need to call Go as a library from uWSGI process?

uWSGI are usually for interpreted languages such as PHP, Python, Ruby and others. It bootstraps the interpreter and manages the master/worker processes to handle requests. It seems strange to be using it on Go library.

You mentioned having nginx as your webserver, why not just use your Go program as the http server (which it does great) and call it from nginx directly using it's URL:

```
location /name/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/go_url/;
}
```

[See nginx docs.](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

If you really want to use Go as a python imported library via a .so module, you have to be aware Go has its own runtime, thread management and may not work well with uWSGI which handles threads/processes in a different way. In this case I'm unable to help you, since I never actually tried this.

If you could clarify your question with what are you actually tring to do, we might me able to answer more helpfully.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to separate this library from main application. I don't want to create another process for this small Go library to be listened by nginx and handling authentication and stuff.

Comment: Well, in that case, try to run the Go library in its own uWSGI process, but one set to have only 1 worker. I'm not sure how Go's runtime would work with uWSGI worker management. Also it should not use worker threads but processes, since Go handles its own threads.

Answer (score 0):

My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915060/3124746) works in some cases. HOWEVER, when i tried to run the same project on another server with same OS, same Python, same uWSGI (version, plugins, config files), same requirements, same .so file, it freezed the save way as i described in answer.

I personally didn't want to run this as separate process and bind it to socket/port and create API for communicating with shared library.

### The solution:

Required only separate process. Run with `celery`.

### Some caveats:

1.You cannot run task with `task.apply()` since it would be run in main application, not in `celery`:

```
result = task.apply_async()
while result.ready():
    time.wait(5)
```

2.You neeed to run `celery` with [`solo`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.concurrency.solo.html) execution pool

```
celery -A app worker -P solo
```